# Grouped GridView. C#. Windows 8

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8

I've done a lot of samples but nowhere encountered on my problem.
Namely, I would like to create a Grouped GridView, which consists of two groups, with the exception that each group is made up of completely different collection. For example, I would like to in the first group were Animals, and in the second, Cars.

I would also like to each of these groups had a different Template ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make both your inner collection items derive from a common base class.  When I did this I had an ItemBase class, and my Event, Story, and Party classes all derived from Item base.

Then, my groups collection items each contained a definition for Items of ObservableCollection.  (I guess, thinking about it now, I could have used object as the implied base type, but I didn't)  When coded this was actually populated with my derived classes, e.g.

```
Items.Add(new Event { Title = "I am an event" };
```

When you display the items in your grid, you will want to create a new class that derives from [ItemTemplateSelector, and override the SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.selecttemplatecore) method.  My logic was as simple as

```
if(item is Event) { return EventTemplate; }
else if(item is Story) { return StoryTemplate }
else { return DefaultTemplate; }
```

(My Party item used the default template.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a ObservableCollection and push your collection items.
Like This:

```
public class ScreenGroupModel
    {       

        private ObservableCollection<object> _groupItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();


        public ObservableCollection<object> GroupItems
        {
            get { return this._groupItems; }
        }

        public ScreenGroupModel()
        {

        }      


        public ObservableCollection<object> GetScreenGroups()
        {            
            _groupItems.Add(new Class1);
            _groupItems.Add(new Class2);           

            return _groupItems;
        }       
    }
```

This Sample, simple collection showing. You can be used DataTemplateSelectors. Every kind of class, select a template. 
ObservableCollection -> "object" type is important. Because, object is base type. You can be add, every kind class.
Regards ;)